# How to build a contact that allow rating?

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, solidity

If I have a contract that has a list of sellers, how would I code a simple contract that if some condition applies, the contract in an automatic way will increase the reputation/rating of the sender ??

Answer (score 1):

This is a very broad question, but one solution would be to simply assign a mapping `mapping(address => uint256) public rating` that increments upon a good action and decrements upon a bad one.

For example, if the user successfully completes a payment, you can increment their rating mapping by one with `rating[user] += 1`.